# Channels other than default in Expo Go?

Tags: expo, expo-go, expo-publish

I have published my app using

```
expo publish --release-channel channelxyz
```

but the only channel I see in my (iOS) Expo Go app is `default`.

How do I get `channelxyz` to appear in the Expo Go app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to feature requests in Expo and in [this thread](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/see-all-release-channels-and-delete-them-from-expo-siteapp):

Release channels are currently visible in the web UI, and through the EAS CLI. The upcoming version of Expo Go and Development Client will also include functionality for this in the apps.